# Flutter Listview Builder Without Specific Height

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

How to make flutter ListView.builder without a specific height(dynamic or not declare the height)
I want to make a list of item, and then when the item going to full height it will wrapped
When i run this code, it returns error because it need height and width
I want to make the list of item like this
[image: Movie Genres]

```
           Wrap(
                spacing: 12,
                runSpacing: 10,
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: movieDetail['genre'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        child: Container(
                          color: darkGrayColor,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 4, horizontal: 12),
                            child: Text('Testing', style: secondaryInfoText),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView.builder

```
GridView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: movieDetail['genre'].length,
              gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 1),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
...
}
```